# window.crypto.subtle.generateKey sometimes not resolving until interaction with the screen

Tags: javascript, html, subtlecrypto

For some reason the call to `window.crypto.subtle.generateKey` works as expected 95% of the time, but occasionnaly the function wil simply not resolve, blocking the rest of the execution.

This remains the case until the user clicks on the screen, and the function immediately resolves.

```js
const key = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
  {
    name: 'AES-GCM',
    length: 256,
  },
  true,
  ['encrypt']
)
```

Anyone already encountered this issue? I wasn't able to find any information on it